# Why am I getting ./filename with file name when searching for files in Unix?

Tags: find

Please check below commands for reference

```
Rinku@Akash ~/test
$ find . -type f -name "autosys*"
./autosys1.txt
./autosys2.txt
```

I don't want the source path added to the found file names.

Comment: Because that's their path? `find` prints the full path of the file.

Comment: Do any of the existing answers solve your problem? If so, please indicate so with the checkmark, or else let us know what's missing. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`find` outputs any matching files with the source-path as a prefix to each one. Compare with:

```
 find $PWD -type f -name "autosys*"
```

Comment: i dont want source path is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean `source path`?  What is you want to see?

Comment: Source path is where you tell find to start finding.

Answer (score 1):

Because `find`s entry point is `.`, actually your `pwd`. If the entry point would be e.g. `/` then this part of the path would be prepended to your `pwd` like this:

```
$ find / -type f -name "autosys*"
/path/from/root/to/$HOME/to/pwd/autosys1.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can strip the leading part of the path by passing the filenames through `sed`.

```
find . -type f -name "autosys*" | sed 's!^\./!!'
```

This will fail for files that contain an embedded newline; if this is an issue you need to consider alternative solutions. However, since `./` is a valid component of a pathname and it has no effect there is nothing technically to be gained by removing it. (It does look nicer, though.)